# Equation of line from PPM vs Voltage for sensor.

Tags: regression

I have an Electrochemical Hydrogen sensor that I am trying to convert its analogue values to PPM values. I am attempting to follow the datasheet and come up with an equation of the line so I can get a formula into which I put the voltage, and out the other side comes PPM.

I have tried interpolating using Wolphram Mathematica but what is produced is a lengthy polynomial that hits all the points I plotted based on the graph shown, although it is wildly off-track in between the points because it makes a line that waves up and down instead of a sort of single curve like is on the graph.

This is the graph that I am attempting to turn into a formula:

[MQ8 Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkZiV.png)

And this is the full datasheet:
[Datasheet Link Winsen MQ-8](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-8%20Ver1.3%20-%20Manual.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fitting of a model such as $y=a+b\:e^{p\:x}$ is not accurate.

A much better result is achieved with two exponentials :
$$y=a+b\:e^{p\:x}+c\:e^{q\:x}$$
The numerical calculus below leads to an asymptote : $y_{max}= a\simeq 3.51$

The existence of a minimum value $\quad y_{min}= a+b+c\simeq 0.28\quad$ at $x=0\quad$ appears consistent with the fact that, even without hydrogen in the sensor, a residual output remains due to other gaz and/or other heat conduction phenomena.

The data used consists in 12 points $(x_k,y_k)$ taken in scanning the graph provided by user2385411.

[image]

Drawn on the original graph, the fitted curve appears in red :

[image]

The very good fitting was carried out thanks to the method from the paper https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales , pp.71-74.

From this paper, the procedure is :

[image]

Comment: Merci! This was incredibly useful... Its a little complex but I'm sure my colleague and I will wrap our heads around it... I had a feeling that some sort of superposition of graphs might be useful

Comment: Only one thing though... how would I go about finding the inverse of this function? I already have 'y' from the voltage at the sensor and I am trying to get the PPM from that not the other way round. Also would I be right in thinking that this is a Lambert-W function?

Comment: The Lambert-W function is of no use in case of two exponentials. On theoretical viewpoint, there is no closed form for the inverse function. On practical application, numerical calculus is required.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like $V=V_0(1-e^{-C/C_0})$ You might need to add a background to it as well. $V_0$ is the voltage when concentration $C$ goes to infinity. $C_0$ is a constant that you need to fit, that tells how fast your curve converges to the maximum value. Just by looking at the graph, $V_0\approx3.5$ and $C_0\approx 200$